# Looking for the correct way to compare 2 entries of an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare two entries of an array, but I'm a bit struggling figuring out the right way to write it correctly.

```
<?php 
     if ($file['name']['link'] != ('user-directory, user')): 
?>
```

What is the right way to check if my two entries `name` and `link` are, respectively, different from "user-directory" and "user"?

**Edit :** To be a bit more specific about what I am trying to do, I want to exclude a specific file that is unique by both its variable `$file['name']` and `$file['link']` combined.

What I mean is that I have other files having either the same `['name']` or `['link']` than the file I'm trying to exclude, but none of them has `$file['name'] = user-directory` and `$file['link'] = user` at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

You are comparing *different* variables to different values, so it's the second below that applies:

```
 // You want that not even one of these checks is true.
 if (!(
      ('user-directory' === $file['name')
      ||
      ('user' === $file['link')
      //...other..
  )) {
     // If all of them fail...
     echo "Well done!";
  } else {
     // But if even one triggers...
     echo "You broke the rules!"
  }
```

In a *different* situation, you could use `in_array` to compare **always the same variable** against a **list**:

```
if (!in_array($file['namelink'], [ 'user-directory', 'user' ]) {

   ...
}
```

The [ ] array is for a recent PHP. Otherwise use `array('user-directory','user')`

This has the advantage of quickly and cleanly adding more items to the list of matching words.

If you want a more fine-grained control on the conditions, or if the conditions are different (e.g. different variables), you'll have to use several clauses joined by the && operator (AND), or || (OR):

```
// None of these conditions must be true,
// i.e. it must never be that condition 1 is true OR condition 2 is, etc.
if (!(
     // Request for user directory
     ('user-directory' === $file['name'])
     ||
     // Request for user, when user is admin
     (('user' === $file['link']) && ('admin' === $_USER))
     ||
     ...// More conditions...
 )) {
    ...
 }
```

The === is because in some cases PHP will try to "help" you in comparing things, and so for example `0 == "one"` is true. The string before the === instead of after is because, on the off chance I mistype a =,

```
// This typo makes it so anyone can login.
if ($input['password'] = 'Squeamish Ossifrage')

// This typo is a syntax error and blows the script
if ('Squeamish Ossifrage' = $input['password'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately you main suggestion doesn't seem to be working in my case, can you explain a bit more about your second one ? I'm pretty new in php :/

Comment: So was I not too long ago :-) -- it's something you grow out of. Edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for theses explanations ! I'm still not too sure what my solution is (trying to fully understand this) but I get why I was wrong, i was under the impression that I was trying to compare 2 parameters (name and link) of one variable (the file in question) but it's actually 2 variables indeed. I will also update my post to get it more specific, thaanks again for all this

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `$file` is an array that has two keys (`name` and `link`), so you will have to perform two checks, one for each key by using `&&`:

```
<?php 
     $compare = array("user-directory", "user");
     if (!in_array($file['name'], $compare) && !in_array($file['link'], $compare)): 
?>
```

Otherwise, if `$file['name']` should be different to `user-directory` and `$file['link']` should be different to `user`:

```
<?php 
     if ($file['name'] != 'user-directory' && $file['link'] != 'user'): 
?>
```

Maybe you wan't to check whether one or the other keys are different, in that case, you should use the `||` operator:

```
<?php 
     if ($file['name'] != 'user-directory' || $file['link'] != 'user'): 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is partially working for me, unfortunately it seems to be comparing the two keys separately, so I end up having all the  $file with the name 'user' being excluded aswell, maybe I went wrong womewhere i'll check and come back to you, thanks again

Comment: Yes, your second code is what I originally did but that is not what I was looking for, as you mentionned I'm looking to check if there is a $file that has both theses keys at the same time

Comment: I don't fully understand, you should probably add to your question two $file arrays, one that you want to be excluded, and one that you don't want to be excluded so I can create a condition that suits your needs